# Witcher 2 Encumbrance Bug

Tags: the-witcher-2

I beat The Witcher 2 for the first time last week, and I'm looking to play through the game a second time taking Roche's path (whom I avoided the first time 'round).

I made my way through the prologue without any problems, got Aryan LaVallette to help me escape, and made it onto Roche's ship without problems.

However, *as soon as* I start chapter 1 and regain the items I collected in the prologue, I become encumbered, at some 333/300. No big deal, right? Just drop the five pickaxes I'm carrying, and I'm good to go!

However, I've now reduced my weight to 95/300, and I'm *still* stuck in the encumbered state, meaning no combat, no meditating, and slow zombie shuffling everywhere I want to go.

I've tried reloading the save, and re-completing the escape from the LaVallette prisons, but neither way prevents the bug from getting me stuck in the encumbered state. I didn't have this problem on my first playthrough... what's going on?

(I have updated to the 1.1 international version prior to beginning the new game)

Edit: This bug is still present. I updated to 1.2 and redid the prologue, to no avail. This time I wound up being 212 / 300, though I'm still stuck as being encumbered. I'm wondering if the bug is linked to the strong back perk itself, as I had no problems when I dueled Arayn (and thus missed the ability) in my first playthrough

Comment: Possible workaround: Install one of the mods that make all items weigh 0, then you can never become encumbered and might not trigger this bug.

Comment: Maybe your caps-lock key is on by accident?

Comment: What does caps-lock do?

Comment: Forgot an @Mana ...

Comment: @Raven It's like holding Shift down, so it keeps your character walking.

Comment: @mANA - Nope. nO combination of shift and/or caps lock helped.

Comment: @Raven I liked your original comment better :'( why did you tone it down.

Comment: @Mana - I was afraid of being moderated by Badp. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm beginning to question whether this is truly a bug at all.

Regardless, I found out how to resolve the problem; Simply continue along the forest path until you meet Iorveth and Triss puts up the arrow shield. At that point, assuming you're currently unencumbered, you will regain your normal speed.

Comment: I am playing this on the XBox, and I ran into the same situation as well.  I actually was not encumbered at all when I got off the boat, but suffered the "slowdown" until I caught up to them at the ambush site.  Perhaps the developers wanted us to walk along the river? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. Until you reach the cutscene with the elf you're forced to walk only even if you are not encumbered. I had 500 pounds of gear and waited until after the hanging to sell it all off to a merchant (fairly easy to fight under the shield while encumbered).